# Force dot after abbreviated author's first name

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biblatex: no period/dot after initials if bibtex-entry firstname is only one letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49394/biblatex-no-period-dot-after-initials-if-bibtex-entry-firstname-is-only-one-let)

I have a pretty large and messy BiBTeX file (who hasn't?), and I would like biblatex to clean up a little the mess. In particular, I would like to abbreviate all authors' first name with a single letter followed by a dot. I used the option `firstinits=true`, but when the original entry is already abbreviated without a dot, it does not add it for consistency.

Is there a way of doing this?