# Biblatex not putting a dot behind "abbreviated" single character author name

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, punctuation

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49394/66983) it is claimed that using `biber` as backend is enough to correctly "abbreviate" with a dot author names given as a single character, however, from my MWE it does not seem like this would be the solution. Am I overlooking something? My .bib database is produced by Mendeley and there are too many such "one-letter-name" entries to do it manually.

(I am using a thesis template downloaded from [here](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/).)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,doi=false,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{database.bib}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@article{Fujisawa:2015nla,
author         = "Fujisawa, K",
title          = "{Magnetised stars with differential rotation and a differential toroidal field}",
doi            = "10.1093/mnras/stv905",
year           = "2015",
eprint         = "1504.05961",
archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
primaryClass   = "astro-ph.HE"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
This reference has mixed fonts~\cite{Fujisawa:2015nla}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the name exactly “K”? If not, why not adding the period in the `bib` file?

Comment: @egreg Question updated. Because I have too many entries in my database with this problem, so I would like to make it automatic.

Comment: Add `firstinits=true` to the options for `biblatex` (the default is “false”).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` will not abbreviate first and middle names unless you add the

```
firstinits=true
```

option.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Fujisawa:2015nla,
author         = "Fujisawa, K",
title          = "{Magnetised stars with differential rotation and a differential toroidal field}",
doi            = "10.1093/mnras/stv905",
year           = "2015",
eprint         = "1504.05961",
archivePrefix  = "arXiv",
primaryClass   = "astro-ph.HE"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,doi=false,url=false,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This reference has mixed fonts~\cite{Fujisawa:2015nla}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works! :-)