# Insert period after initial using biblatex also some additional requirements

Tags: biblatex

My tags are as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
% BibTeX bibliography file
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\setlength{\bibhang}{5\p@}%
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{3\p@}%
\def\bibfont{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont}%
\renewcommand{\RNfont}{}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{document}



\cite{anderson2013adaptive}

\cite{chater2008probabilistic}

\cite{craver2007explaining}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**content of the .bib file**

```
@book{anderson2013adaptive,
  title={The adaptive character of thought},
  author={Anderson, John R},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Psychology Press}
}

@book{chater2008probabilistic,
  title={The probabilistic mind: Prospects for Bayesian cognitive science},
  author={Chater, Nick and Oaksford, Mike and others},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Oxford University Press, USA}
}

@book{craver2007explaining,
  title={Explaining the brain: Mechanisms and the mosaic unity of neuroscience},
  author={Craver, Carl F},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Clarendon Press}
}
```

Current code produced the output as:

[image]

But my requirement is:

[image]

I've tried with [Biblatex: no period/dot after initials if bibtex-entry firstname is only one letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49394/biblatex-no-period-dot-after-initials-if-bibtex-entry-firstname-is-only-one-let) but no luck...

Please suggest how to achieve

Comment: (1) Just a wild guess: Did you try if using `babel` makes a difference (incl. setting a language)? (2) Not related, but AFAIK, using `backend=biber` is not needed for many years now.

Comment: Also, please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407 on how to make a good `biblatex` MWE (`filecontents`) or use `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` for example.

Comment: Last stupid comment: What happens if you add a period in `author={Anderson, John R},`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner If add the period in `author={Anderson, John R.}`, then it works fine, sorry, it won't strike for me, can you suggest how to add `and` as shown in my second entry? please...

Comment: Please ask only about one issue per question. That makes your question easier to answer and more useful for other people. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864. Please also describe in more detail what exactly you need.

Comment: Sir @moewe now the only issue as shown in second entry, first and third entries issue fixed as suggested by `Dr Manuel`, please suggest...

Comment: I suggest you accept Manuel's answer below and ask a new and clear question about your remaining issues (don't just post pictures of the status quo and what you want, but *also* explain what exactly needs to be changed - pictures are great, but not as the *only* source of explanation).

Comment: Will do as you suggested, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment to answer for the main question: Add the period after the initial in the bib database.

`author={Anderson, John R.},`